# How to add new packages when using an Azure Artifcat as package source

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget, azure-artifacts

Due to our obfuscasting library(Babel4), we had to create a Azure artifact to host their nuget package.

It works fine, but if we try to add a package that has never been referenced in our .Net Core project(in visual studio), we cannot find it.

I was able to manually install it through the command line:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson
```

but then on another computer if I try to restore the references, I get this error:

```
  XXX.YYY: [NU1101] Unable to find package 
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.NewtonsoftJson. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Babel3
```

(Babel3 is our artifact name).

But Azure Artifacts has Nuget(and other) configured as upstream sources:
[image]

On Azure Artifact, if I try to look for a package that I don't have installed, it doesn't find it(and I'm owner of the artifact):
[image]

What should I do? Configure another package source in Visual Studio? Something on azure?

Thank you very much

**EDIT**
Here is is my nuget.config if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="Babel3" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXX/_packaging/Babel3/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages\" />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="packages\" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Feed settings for Babel3 -> Check if you have added "Project Collection Build Service(org)" and "project build service(org)" as collaborator, contributor, or owner role. As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#q-can-a-user-with-reader-role-download-packages-from-an-upstream-source), if you don't have enough permission on feed, the pipeline cannot fetch package from upstream.

[image]
[image]

I can fetch the nuget package from upstream to local feed.
[image]

BTW, please make sure the project settings -> pipelines -> settings -> Job authroized scope is not limited if the feed from another project.
[image]

Edit:
Since you restore from local machine and "nuget gallery" is public resource. Please try to add it directly in nuget.config.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. My problem is not when executing a Azure Devop Job, but on my local machine, so it should not use the build services. My account has an owner role, and the account you mentionned have the contributor role.

Comment: If you store from local machine, please follow [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) to check the nuget.config file is correctly configured. Also please make sure public nuget gallery is not blocked on the agent.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're talking about. I don't "store" anything, I'm not yet in an azure job, I'm in Visual Studio on my dev computer, with Azure Devop Artifact as source, so nothing to do with an agent. I can retrieve those packages when in another project, it's just when I'm using this project, with Azure Devop Artifact as source, I cannot find any package that isn't already installed. We have tested this with 3 other computer of the team, it's the same thing, so it's definitely something to do with either Azure devop artifact or the way the nuget is configured.

Comment: I've checked your link, it seems to be coherent with my upstream sources(see screenshot) and nuget.config(I've added it to the question)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Since it's public source, please give a try to add the source as "<packageSources>...</packageSources>" directly in nuget.config, check if it fetch the package in this senario. Please check [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesources) for the setting details.

Comment: That works, but now if i'm correct, it doesn't use at all the upstream feature, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it will download packaged from source but not upstream. To troubleshoot for the upstream feature, can you check the local command details, whether it will go to Azure feed to fetch the package and it's successful? Could it use local cached pacakge? If so, the network could block the connection to azure feed. Or you can also add a new self-defined package (not cached locally)in feed and try to consume for confirmation.

Comment: How to debug the local command? I'm using Visual studio Nuget package manager, is there some output somewhere?

Comment: You can use [nuget restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-by-using-the-nuget-cli) or [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-by-using-the-dotnet-cli) command, check the output of the result.

Comment: It's weird because, if I try to do the "upstream way"  to install XUNIT from visual studio, it doesn't work, but if I run `dotnet add package xunit` in the package manager console, it does work.

Comment: It's mostly like the network setting issue, please follow the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4) to check the url, ips related.

Comment: But it works for packages in the list. That's weird....